# Create list of several datasets

Tags: python, pandas

I have several datasets like df_1,df_2,...df_100.
First I want to create a list of these datasets.

```
df=[df_1,df_2,...,df_100]
```

This is what I did which did not work for me.

```
df=[]
for i in range(1,101):
    df.append("df_"+str(i))
```

I need the above one so that I do the following

```
final=pandas.concat(df,ignore_index=True)
```

This gives me an error since df is a list of strings, not datasets. I want to create a list of several datasets.

In R, I did the following

```
final=do.call(rbind,mget(paste0("df_",1:100)))
```

Is there anything similar in python?

Comment: what are you creating the datasets from ?

Comment: you could create a dictionary i.e `{f"df_{i}" : pd.DataFrame(...), for i in range(1,101)}`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, Manakin. But I do not understand how I would create dictionary like you said. Please elaborate.

Comment: This isn't the best practice for code but maybe you couold use eval, so you'd do `df.append(eval("df_"+str(i)))` and that might work. But again, using eval is generally not the best.

Comment: Thank you for such an easy fix, user15270287 .

Comment: May I know why eval is not generally best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use built-in functions `globals` or `locals` to get variable by name

```
>>> [globals()[d] for d in df]
```

Example:

```
>>> df_1
                   A         B         C
9l6rvsotz5  0.209350 -1.360556  0.059560
jTonmSOIVv  1.046584  0.251718  0.567056
eGaK0n8y9N -0.347716 -0.292623  0.591843

>>> df_2
                   A         B         C
TIVsJWSDWe -0.169969  0.345766  0.674683
EJjXuhL3pi -0.527015 -1.089954 -1.658116
dm3IYAyC7z  1.653666 -0.203685 -1.441150

>>> df_3
                   A         B         C
DbmE1sc3MI  0.215871 -0.382257  0.662477
9qZd6bvPVy  0.150985  0.135556  0.308615
qiVrxD64IF -1.384027  0.765303 -0.734394

>>> df = ["df_{}".format(i) for i in range(1, 4)]
>>> df
['df_1', 'df_2', 'df_3']

>>> pd.concat([globals()[d] for d in df], ignore_index=True)
          A         B         C
0  0.209350 -1.360556  0.059560
1  1.046584  0.251718  0.567056
2 -0.347716 -0.292623  0.591843
3 -0.169969  0.345766  0.674683
4 -0.527015 -1.089954 -1.658116
5  1.653666 -0.203685 -1.441150
6  0.215871 -0.382257  0.662477
7  0.150985  0.135556  0.308615
8 -1.384027  0.765303 -0.734394
```