# How to use a loop to automate a repetitive task?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a function to create a final dataframe and need to apply this function to 10 different dataframes. Is there a way to use a loop to automate this in stead of writing the dataframe name one by one?

```
def table_all(df,sales_date):
  df1=df.loc[df['date']==sales_date]
  ### more code##
  df1.fillna(0,inplace=True)
  return df1

sales1 = table_all(df,sales_date1)
sales2 = table_all(df,sales_date2)
sales3 = table_all(df,sales_date3)
##### more code ####
sales10 = table_all(df,sales_date10)
```

I am hoping to use a loop like below but it did not work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
for x in range(1,11):
   sales+str(x)=table_all(df, sales_date+str(x))
```

Comment: do you need to have fixed names? If not, you might have a list of names and dates. Then you can more easily for sale,date in zip(sale_names_list, date_list): ...

Comment: The name for the dataframe will be sales1, sales2 and so on. The date will be salesdate1, salesdate2 and so on. Do you mind to give me an example on how to use zip in this scenario ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer use a `dict` to store results:

```
sales = {}
for x in range(1, 11):
    sales[x] = table_all(df, globals()["sales_date{}".format(x)]
```

Pretty much the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66373254/create-list-of-several-datasets)